# BlackBerryMessenger: Get the Error in net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar file

Tags: blackberry

When I run the sample demos that provided by **BBM SDK v1.1 for BlackBerry Java** and as well as in **BBM SDK v1.2 for BlackBerry Java**, I am not able to run the file. For this I preverify the **net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar** file of both versions I get the following **Error** in command prompt:

[image: PreVerify the Jar file]

Then I extract the **net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar** file and check the class
**net.rim.blackberry.api.bbm.platform.ui.chat.component.SmilyScreen.class** (I decompile this class with java decompilor and checked) I got the below code:

There I found one interface which is not there in entire jar file and Blackberry **O.S6.0 AND O.S7.0** : Look below:

[image: SmileyScreen]

Here I got one line:
**public final class SmileyScreen extends PopupScreen implements FieldChangeListener, FocusChangeListener, TextInputDialog**

I don't have **TextInputDialog** this class.

I checked this at: **import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TextInputDialog;**
But I didn't get **TextInputDialog** this interface in **O.S6 AND O.S7.**

Because of this reason I got **"Not Registered"** in the Signin tool.

If I am fault please tell me how to run the Blackberry Messenger by using net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar file.

Actually I don't need to do preverify the jar file. I verified because I got the following problem when sighIn the application:

[image: SignIn Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to verify the BBM jars, just your own application.  It doesn't look like you are passing in your own application to the preverify command.

---

Regarding verification of BlackberryMessenger.cod, is your app named BlackberryMessenger?  It sounds like you are verifying the BBM app from RIM.   RIM is able to use APIs which are not available to third-party developers, so the third party signing keys won't work.  You should be signing your own app, not BBM.

Comment: Check the question once again I edited now that why I am preverify the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

alishaik786
   i had this question when i try to build BBM public demo,and finally find out the reason.

Don't need check net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar in the Order and Export tab,and also don't need to preverify this jar . The jar is include By BBM(version 6.0 above),your app just need add this jar when compile.

Download a BBM v6.1 enabled simulator,link as http://us.blackberry.com/developers/blackberrymessenger/ . Use these simulator to run this demo.